# Do we need ezpublish_legacy?

Tags: ezpublish

I'm going to start a project from scratch by using ezpublish 5. But i'm not sure do we need ezpublish_legacy (old version) if we dont use it? How to get rid of it for new project with only ezpublish5? I spent hours on google but not found the way to install ezpublish without ezpublish_legacy :(

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eZPublish 5 will always need ezpublish legacy.
We must waiting for eZPublish 6 to run without it. (from an eZSystem's answer)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite temporary : no you don't need it for frontends siteaccesses if you feel confortable in building your website in the new ez5/sf2 way. However, you still need it for the admin interface because it has not been completely rebuilt yet, on top of the new eZ Publish 5 stack. So unless you don't need an admin interface or are planning to write your own, then you need ezpublish_legacy :)

Comment: Many thanks foobar! I want to get rid of ezpublish_legacy because of its size (it makes troubles on source control systems).